# Алгоритмы активного шумоподавления

Tags: алгоритм, аудио, fft, обработка-сигналов

Меня интересуют алгоритмы активного шумоподавления. Углубляясь в детали реализации, выполняется спектральное вычитание "на ходу".

Имеется некоторый профиль шума и небольшой длины запись, из которой этот шум нужно удалить ("вычесть").

Так у меня вопрос по конкретному алгоритму спектрального вычитания: как оно выполняется и, собственно, над чем? В общих чертах я себе это представляю как вычитание из спектра (соответствие частот амплитудам гармоник) сигнала спектра шума и обратное преобразование Фурье. Вообще, вроде как, применяемое здесь FFT даёт не соответствие частот амплитудам, а просто массив комплексных чисел. Как тут вычитать что из чего не представляю...

P.S.: Не нужно давать ссылки на курсы по обработке звука и спектральному анализу сигналов. Просто вопрос - просто ясный ответ.

---

Есть такие специализированные программы, как, например, Noise Gator. Так вот, если кому известно, подскажите, какие алгоритмы шумоподавления ими используются (в частности, используется ли спектральное вычитание; если да, то откуда программа берёт слепок шума).

Comment: Вот тут http://makseq.com/data/rd/Adaptive%20Noise%20Reduction%20(R1).pdf  в разделе  4.1 (3 страницы) расписано на уровне понимания доступном для третьего курса кулинарного техникума. –

Comment: Предлагаемый порядок действий таков: выполнить stft сигнала и шума, составить слепок шума путём получения средних значений Фурье преобразований для каждой частоты среди всех окон сигнала, вычесть из амплитудного спектра сигнала спектр шума (отрицательные результаты заменить на нули), выполнить обратное преобразование. В качестве метода борьбы с "музыкальным шумом" использовать метод рекурсивного сглаживания по времени.

Comment: Что ж. Не совсем ясно каким именно образом выполнять stft. Для начала, сигнал режется на окна - на какое количество этих окон нужно поделить? Что при этом нужно учитывать? Какое именно преобразование затем выполнять над каждым окном? FFT?

Comment: Результат FFT - массив комплексных чисел. О каком амплитудном спектре речь?

Comment: Может я немного не правильно понял смысл результата самого FFT... Верно ли, что вот этот результирующий массив комплексных чисел содержит как информацию об амплитудном, так и о фазовом спектрах? В случае интересующего нас амплитудного спектра, нужно просто посчитать модуль комплексного числа (sqrt(a^2+b^2)).

Comment: "массив комплексных чисел" - это и есть соответствие частот амплитудам... Амплитуды комплексные, а частоты запрятаны в индексах.

Comment: Так понимаю, в таком случае, вычитание будет выполняться между самими комплексными числами, а не между их модулями. _частоты запрятаны в индексах_ - это как? О каких индексах речь?

Comment: В индексах массива. Обычно, Частота = Индекс/Время исходного образца. В том же BASS есть специальная функция FFTIndex2Frequency специально для этой цели.

Comment: Частота = Индекс * Частота дискретизации / Размер массива

Comment: http://www.bass.radio42.com/help/html/b4e1d31d-c607-3560-66b7-bdef7ae96c7c.htm

Comment: Я правильно понял?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Ну хорошо. Допустим с FFT разобрались. По окнам не знаете?

Comment: Про тип оконной функции можно ли поподробнее? Слышал я про разные оконные Фурье функции типа Хэмминга, Блэкмана. Но где это применяется? Вроде как после получения спектра сигнала, чтобы не возникло эффекта спектральной утечки, нужно перемножить окно на такую оконную функцию. Но как именно это выполняется? Оконная функция должна быть представлена массивом чисел, на элементы которого я должен соответственно по индексам помножить элементы массива представляющего результат FFT моего сигнала?

Comment: @D.Stark на оконную функцию умножают сам сигнал. Подробнее в ответе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритмы удаления шума невозможно рассмотреть без углубления в математику, акустику и теорию спектрального анализа сигналов.

Любой анализ сигнала с помощью преобразований Фурье предполагает, что сигнал является стационарным на исследуемом отрезке. Поэтому, если сигнал нестационарный, он разбивается на отдельные отрезки, называемые окнами. Выбор размера окна зависит от типа исследуемого сигнала, обычно около 25 - 50 мс для звукового сигнала (меньшие значения - для человеческой речи, большие - для музыки, особенно состоящей из струнных смычковых инструментов). Можно использовать перекрывающиеся окна, для повышения точности анализа.

Однако, просто так применить преобразование Фурье к обрезанным окнам нельзя, при этом некорректно обрабатываются граничные области отрезков. Для решения этой проблемы сигнал предварительно умножают на специальную весовую функцию ("оконную"). Примеры оконных функций см. в статье [Оконное преобразование Фурье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5)

Далее выполняется непосредственно преобразование Фурье. Оно дает в результате спектр сигнала, т.е. значение комплексной амплитуды для различных диапазонов частот. Из него и надо вычитать спектр шума. Из модуля комплексной амплитуды сигнала вычитается модуль комплексной амплитуды шума, умноженный на некий коэффициент; если результат отрицательный, он заменяется на ноль. Фазовый компонент оставляется нетронутым. К результату вычитания можно применить обратное преобразование Фурье, и получить "очищенный" сигнал.

**Итоговый алгоритм шумоподавления при наличии известного образца шума:**

1. Разделение сигнала на окна
2. Применение оконного преобразования Фурье к окнам
3. Вычитание (по модулю) спектра амплитуды шума из спектра амплитуды сигнала:

> A = Max ( A с. - k * А ш. ; 0)

где k - коэффициент, подбираемый опытным путем

4. Применение обратного преобразования Фурье к результату

Размер окна, перекрытие окон, тип применяемой оконной функции подбираются опытным путем.

**Ссылки**

[Removing noise from audio using Fourier transform in Matlab](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9054/removing-noise-from-audio-using-fourier-transform-in-matlab)

[How can I select an optimal window for Short Time Fourier Transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863232/how-can-i-select-an-optimal-window-for-short-time-fourier-transform)

[How to select frequency resolution and window size in FFT?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79647/how-to-select-frequency-resolution-and-window-size-in-fft)

Comment: _k - коэффициент, подбираемый опытным путем_ - в каком интервале значений он должен быть? Примерно хотя бы.

Comment: _Применение обратного преобразования Фурье к результату_ - вот реализаций FFT в сети можно найти много, чего не скажем об обратном преобразовании. У вас не будет каких либо ссылок на примеры реализации обратного FFT, где функции передаётся просто массив комплексных чисел (ну наш обработанный массив)?

Comment: На счёт вычитания спектра амплитуды шума из спектра амплитуды сигнала: исходя из того, что мы имеем представление FFT сигнала в виде массива комплексных чисел, амплитуда сигнала есть модуль комплексного числа, а фаза - аргумент; так вот, говоря о вашей формуле, вроде как нужно же не вычитать, а умножать (применение цифрового фильтра). Давайте будем исходить из того, что мы имеем 2 комплексных числа - одно из FFT сигнала шума, другое из FFT обрабатываемого сигнала. Что с ними нужно делать?

Comment: @D.Stark "от реализаций FFT в сети можно найти много, чего не скажем об обратном преобразовании" http://www.fftw.org/

Comment: "Что с ними нужно делать?" То, что написано. Найти модуль и аргумент, с модулем произвести математическую операцию, аргумент не трогать, потом преобразовать снова в комплексное число.

Comment: А на счёт коэффициента что скажете?

Comment: _"Что с ними нужно делать?" То, что написано. Найти модуль и аргумент, с модулем произвести математическую операцию, аргумент не трогать, потом преобразовать снова в комплексное число._ - точно. Есть же формула: z=A(cos fi + sin fi * i) где A - амплитула, fi - фаза.

Comment: @D.Stark коэффициент k определяется тем, как соотносится громкость образца шума и громкость обрабатываемого звука. Если она примерно одинакова, то 1. Если шум в образце слишком тихий, то больше единицы.

Answer (score 2):

Вы уже задавали этот вопрос, а я отвечал. Попытаюсь ответить лучше, чем в прошлый раз.

> ОКНО

Пусть шум это синус (наводка сети электроснабжения, например). Фотографируем фрагмент шума, чтобы потом алгоритмом FFT получить его спектр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кажется, что это синус, но на самом деле это вот что:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Резкий перепад, выделенный красным - это очень сильное искажение. Если вы прослушаете это в наушниках ушами, то поймете, что это совсем не тот шум, который вы хотите вычесть из своего сигнала. Чтобы уменьшить искажение, применяется окно (не ликвидировать, ведь окно само вносит искажения в сигнал):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат применения окна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это была работа с образцом шума.

Теперь можно выполнить БПФ на этом образце шума и получить его спектр. Дальше, на каждом входном блоке сигнала можно так же выполнить БПФ и получить его спектр.

Что получится, если попытаться вычесть на каждой частоте абсолютное значение спектра шума из абсолютного значения спектра сигнала. Получится то, что этой операции в принципе соответствует умножение спектра данного блока сигнала на некоторый другой спектр, то есть применение цифрового фильтра. Только для следующего блока входного сигнала этот фильтр будет уже другим. В результате ситуация будет примерно как на второй картинке - разрывы на границах блоков.

Лично я вышел из этой ситуации следующим образом: применял к блоку сигнала сразу оба фильтра и линейно интерполировал результат, то есть в первой точке блока сигнала действовал только первый фильтр, в последней - только второй, и так линейно.

Comment: Получается, применение оконной функции выполняется не к спектру, а к самому сигналу. Каким образом это действие выполняется на практике? Что на что "умножить"?

Comment: _операции в принципе соответствует умножение спектра данного блока сигнала на некоторый другой спектр, то есть применение цифрового фильтра_ - Ну а умножать что на что в спектре? По индексам перемножать массивы fft комплексных чисел сигнала и шума? _Только для следующего блока входного сигнала этот фильтр будет уже другим_ - Всм должен быть другим? Почему? У нас есть слепок шума. Он меняться как то должен?

Comment: _операции в принципе соответствует умножение спектра данного блока сигнала на некоторый другой спектр, то есть применение цифрового фильтра_ - или речь именно о перемножении комплексных значений амплитуд спектрах соответственно по частотам?